# How to ensure backup of Google Analytics Universal data after its discontinuation?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics, looker-studio

I would like to know if after the discontinuation of google analytics universal will it be possible to consult the data and for how long after the end of 2023? Anybody know?

I question this because I have several dashboards in Looker Studio linked to UA properties and I don't know if the data is still active afterwards. I will probably have to export from analytics and import into looker studio to keep this past data backup.

From what I've seen since December UA stops recording data but I don't know if they are still available on the analytics platform or if I need to back up the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently several ways to export data from your Universal Analytics property.

[Export individual reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1038573) into the following formats:

- CSV
- TSV
- TSV for Excel
- Excel (XLSX)
- Google Sheets
- PDF
- Use the Google Analytics Reporting API to export data
- Google Analytics 360 customers can also export to BigQuery

See: [Universal Analytics is going away](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en#zippy=%2Chow-can-i-export-data-from-my-universal-analytics-property)